# Attribute in C# function parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

My mentor modified my first C# program to help it conform to language conventions and then had to leave town for a couple days. I'm trying to work through what he changed and I understand almost all of it. The only part I'm missing is the following:

```
public IEnumerable<DataType> SelectPerson([Control("txtPersonName")] string sPersonName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sPersonName)) return null;
        return Util.SearchDatabase(sPersonName);
    }
```

Specifically, I don't understand this section:

```
[Control("txtPersonName")] string sPersonName
```

### Some context

txtPersonName is an asp TextBox.

ddlPerson is an asp DropDownList.

ddlPerson.SelectMethod = "SelectPerson" file is this only place the function is referenced.

As far as I can tell, the code snippet is just creating a local variable sPersonName of type string with the value "txtPersonName". Is there something else here?

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? You can right click on Control and then click Go To Definition to see what it does. Or press F12 on your keyboard.

Comment: I don't know a `ControlAttribute`, but I guess you are using it for some kind of (static) analysis. I can imagine that it helps to analyze the dataflow from ui to backend or something like that. So you can analyse that the value entered in that textbox is finally used in this method.

Comment: It is very rare to add attributes to parameters of a method. I concur on what René wrote.

Comment: I'll add that if you search for the word `ControlAttribute` in all the files of the solution, there is the possibility that you'll find the piece of code that analyzes it. You should find the words `GetParameters` and `GetCustomAttributes` near it.

Comment: Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691808/square-bracket-syntax-in-functions-parameter-in-c) and also [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.modelbinding.controlattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Right click on control and then select go to definition, it will tell you what it's about.  Now those type of parameters are used to "automatically" allow injection of what is expected by the framework.  I've never used the control attribute but have used others.

Comment: Thanks @EmmanuelDurai, those got me on the right track.